# Not a valid JAR from testing hadoop mapreduce wordcount

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

New to Hadoop Mapreduce and I am not sure why I am getting this error.

I am currently getting:

`Not a valid JAR: /nfsdata/DSCluster/home/user/bli1/wordcount/wc.jar`

This is my process:

HDFS file structure:

```
   /bli1
      /wordcount
         wc.jar
         WordCount.java
         /input
            file01
         /output
            file02
```

1. Create on local machine `WordCount.java` and `wc.jar` with `jar cf wc.jar WordCount.java`
2. Create on local machine  `file01` and `file02`
3. Create `/input` and `/output` directory within `/wordcount` in hdfs
4. Move files to their directories with hdfs

   - `hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal <localsrc> <dst>`
5. run command:

   hadoop jar /user/bli1/wordcount/wc.jar WordCount /user/bli1/wordcount/input /user/bli1/wordcount/output

OUTPUT:

```
Not a valid JAR: /user/bli1/wordcount/wc.jar
```

I tried this to make the JAR but I would get an error.

```
$ hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

If this process to make the JAR is different than `jar cf wc.jar WordCount.java` then this might be causing the problem. However I don't know why I am getting the `find or load main class error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liondancer, within the Java jar file you must add the compiled *.class files, not the source *.java files.

In addition, once you resolve the problem, I think most probably Hadoop will complaint about the existence of the output directory. I mean, Hadoop will expect to create itself such an output directory, which must not exist.